# Need help with the python code: Calculating Madelung constant CsCl crystal structure

Tags: python, computational-physics, computational-geometry, computational-chemistry

Need help with the code to estimate the Madelung constant for CsCl lattice:

Cs at (0,0,0)

Cl at (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)

Answer: Converged value I am getting is `0.465`. However, the correct answer is approximately `1.763`.

What am I doing wrong? Code as below.

```
M = 0
L = 10

for i in range(-L,L+1):
    for j in range(-L,L+1):
        for k in range(-L,L+1):
            if (i==0 and j==0 and k==0):
                #negative ion
                a = i+0.5
                b = j+0.5
                c = k+0.5
                M += 1/np.sqrt(a*a + b*b + c*c)
            else:
                #postive ion
                M -= 1/np.sqrt(i*i + j*j + k*k)
                #negative ion
                a = i+0.5
                b = j+0.5
                c = k+0.5
                M += 1/np.sqrt(a*a + b*b + c*c)

print('Madelung constant:', M)
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you double count when accounting for offset.

```py
import numpy as np

M = 0
L = 10
for i in range(-L, L + 1):
    for j in range(-L, L + 1):
        for k in range(-L, L + 1):
            if i == 0 and j == 0 and k == 0:
                continue
            if (i+j+k) % 2 == 0:
                sign = -1
            else:
                sign = 1
            r = np.sqrt((i**2) + (j**2) + (k**2))
            M += sign / r
print('Madelung constant:', M)
```

which prints for $L=10$

```py
Madelung constant: 1.6925789282594415
```

and for $L=100$

```py
Madelung constant: 1.7418198158396654
```

You can also plot the convergence using something like this

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def calculate_madelung(L):
    M = 0
    for i in range(-L, L + 1):
        for j in range(-L, L + 1):
            for k in range(-L, L + 1):
                if i == 0 and j == 0 and k == 0:
                   continue
                if (i+j+k) % 2 == 0:
                     sign = -1
                else:
                    sign = 1
                r = np.sqrt((i**2) + (j**2) + (k**2))
                M += sign / r
    print('Madelung constant:', M)
    return M

L_values = range(1, 50) 
M_values = []

for L in L_values:
    M = calculate_madelung(L)
    M_values.append(M)
    print(f'L = {L}, Madelung constant = {M}')

plt.plot(L_values, M_values, marker='o')
plt.xlabel('L')
plt.ylabel('Madelung Constant')
plt.title('Convergence of Madelung Constant for CsCl')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image: Convergence]